# Xamarin Mobile with IdentityServer 3

Tags: xamarin, identityserver3, bearer-token

I am trying to establish a secure connection for my mobile app using Identity server 3 and Xamarin.  I have a web app that works perfectly using the identity server but can’t for the life of me get it working with mobile.  I have it asking for credentials, logging in and getting an access token.  However when I try to make a call using the token I still get HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated as false and the call fails.

I created a new client in the identity server for the mobile app and have it as the following:

```
new IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Client
{
  Enabled = true,
  ClientName = "MyMobile Mobile App",
  ClientId = "myMobile",
  ClientSecrets = { new Secret("myMobileSecret".Sha256()) },
  Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
  RedirectUris = new List<string>
  {
    …
  },
  PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
  {
    …
  },
  RequireConsent = false,
  AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
  RequireSignOutPrompt = false
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
var authorizeRequest = new AuthorizeRequest(GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityEndpoint);

var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("client_id", GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientId);
dic.Add("client_secret", GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientSecret);
dic.Add("response_type", "code token");
dic.Add("scope", "openid profile roles");
dic.Add("redirect_uri", GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityCallback);
dic.Add("nonce", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

_currentCSRFToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
dic.Add("state", _currentCSRFToken);

var authorizeUri = authorizeRequest.Create(dic);           
LoginWebView.Source = authorizeUri;
```

On response…

```
private async Task NavigateAsync(string url)
{
  var unescapedUrl = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(url);

  if (unescapedUrl.StartsWith(GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityCallback))
  {
      LoginWebView.IsVisible = false;

      var authResponse = new AuthorizeResponse(url);
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authResponse.Code))
      {
          var userToken = await _identityService.GetTokenAsync(authResponse.Code);

          string accessToken = userToken.AccessToken;
          if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
          {
              Authorization.AccessToken = accessToken;
              Authorization.IdToken = authResponse.IdentityToken;

              Application.Current.MainPage = _homePage;
          }
      }
  }
  …
}

public async Task<UserToken> GetTokenAsync(string code)
{
  string data = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&code_verifier={2}", code, WebUtility.UrlEncode(GlobalSetting.Instance.IdentityCallback), _codeVerifier);
  var token = await _requestProvider.PostAsync<UserToken> (GlobalSetting.Instance.TokenEndpoint, data, GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientId, GlobalSetting.Instance.ClientSecret);
  return token;
}
```

And then when I make a call…

```
RestClient rest = new RestClient(GlobalSetting.DefaultBaseUrl);

var request = new RestRequest("Partner/GetMyItem", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("detail", MyEnumValue.ToString());

//tried both of the following…
request.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", Authorization.AccessToken), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
rest.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", Authorization.AccessToken));

IRestResponse res = rest.Post(request);
```

Function…

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[AuthAttribute(Roles = …)]
[HandleForbidden]
public string GetMyItem(MyEnum detail)
```

In the server identity log I have the following…

```
2018-07-23 14:03:11.508 +00:00 [Information] Start authorize request
2018-07-23 14:03:11.508 +00:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-07-23 14:03:11.508 +00:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"myMobile\",
  \"ClientName\": \"myMobile App\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"https://localhost:44000/\",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"https://localhost:44000/\",
      ...
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"unknown\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"code token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"fragment\",
  \"Flow\": \"Hybrid\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid profile roles\",
  \"State\": \"a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\",
  \"Nonce\": \"ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"myMobile\",
    \"client_secret\": \"myMobileSecret\",
    \"response_type\": \"code token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid profile roles\",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://localhost:44000/\",
    \"nonce\": \"ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0\",
    \"state\": \"a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\"
  }
}"
2018-07-23 14:03:11.524 +00:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
2018-07-23 14:03:11.524 +00:00 [Information] End authorize request
2018-07-23 14:03:11.524 +00:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
2018-07-23 14:03:11.524 +00:00 [Debug] Protecting message: "{\"ReturnUrl\":\"https://....net/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=myMobile&client_secret=myMobileSecret&response_type=code%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20roles&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44000%    2F&nonce=ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0&state=a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\",\"ClientId\":\"myMobile\",\"AcrValues\":[],\"Created\":636679513915083066}"
2018-07-23 14:03:11.570 +00:00 [Information] Login page requested
2018-07-23 14:03:11.570 +00:00 [Debug] signin message passed to login: "{
  \"ReturnUrl\": \"https://...net/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=myMobile&client_secret=myMobileSecret&response_type=code%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20roles&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44000%    2F&nonce=ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0&state=a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\",
  \"ClientId\": \"myMobile\",
  \"IdP\": null,
  \"Tenant\": null,
  \"LoginHint\": null,
  \"DisplayMode\": null,
  \"UiLocales\": null,
  \"AcrValues\": [],
  \"Created\": 636679513915083066
}"
2018-07-23 14:03:11.570 +00:00 [Information] rendering login page
2018-07-23 14:03:12.007 +00:00 [Information] CSP Report endpoint requested
2018-07-23 14:03:12.007 +00:00 [Information] CSP Report data: "{\"csp-report\":{\"document-uri\":\"https://...net/identity/login?signin=df9bdfc781a634b806ecc6555e9989ca\",\"referrer\":\"\",\"blocked-uri\":\"\",\"violated-directive\":\"script-src 'self'\",\"original-policy\":\"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' ;     style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; img-src *; font-src font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; report-uri https://devs3server.azurewebsites.net/identity/csp/report\",\"effective-directive\":\"script-src\",\"status-code\":200,\"source-    file\":\"https://devs3server.azurewebsites.net/identity/login?signin=df9bdfc781a634b806ecc6555f9989ca\"}}"
2018-07-23 14:03:12.007 +00:00 [Information] Rendering 204
2018-07-23 14:03:26.772 +00:00 [Information] Login page submitted
2018-07-23 14:03:26.803 +00:00 [Information] Login credentials successfully validated by user service
2018-07-23 14:03:26.803 +00:00 [Information] Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
2018-07-23 14:03:26.819 +00:00 [Information] issuing primary signin cookie
2018-07-23 14:03:26.819 +00:00 [Information] redirecting to: https://....net/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=myMobile&client_secret=myMobileSecret&response_type=code token&scope=openid profile roles&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Flocalhost:44000%    2F&nonce=ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0&state=a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70
2018-07-23 14:03:26.866 +00:00 [Information] Start authorize request
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"myMobile\",
  \"ClientName\": \"my Mobile App\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"https://localhost:44000/\",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"https://localhost:44000/\",
    ...
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"2957b247-43ed-4aea-b5b4-c0a76a613942\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"code token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"fragment\",
  \"Flow\": \"Hybrid\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid profile roles\",
  \"State\": \"a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\",
  \"Nonce\": \"ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0\",
  \"SessionId\": \"3e67194d4c5ba7d1c8586948377f9fe7\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"myMobile\",
    \"client_secret\": \"myMobileSecret\",
    \"response_type\": \"code token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid profile roles\",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://localhost:44000/\",
    \"nonce\": \"ec42d50463cc418dacbd04f1c43873d0\",
    \"state\": \"a971d692ae8f424493966023f5934b70\"
  }
}"
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Information] Creating Hybrid Flow response.
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Information] Creating Implicit Flow response.
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Debug] Creating access token
2018-07-23 14:03:26.881 +00:00 [Debug] Creating JWT access token
2018-07-23 14:03:26.912 +00:00 [Debug] Adding client "myMobile" to client list cookie for subject "2957b247-43ed-4aea-b5b4-c0a76a613942"
2018-07-23 14:03:26.912 +00:00 [Information] End authorize request
2018-07-23 14:03:26.912 +00:00 [Information] Redirecting to: https://localhost:44000/
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Start token request
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Debug] Start client validation
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Debug] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Debug] Parser found secret: "BasicAuthenticationSecretParser"
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Secret id found: "myMobile"
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Debug] Secret validator success: "HashedSharedSecretValidator"
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Client validation success
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Start token request validation
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Start validation of authorization code token request
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Validation of authorization code token request success
2018-07-23 14:03:28.950 +00:00 [Information] Token request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "myMobile",
  "ClientName": "my Mobile App",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "AuthorizationCode": "dc7be1793efe246ca817d7d35298b355",
  "Raw": {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": "dc7be1793efe246ca817d7d35298b355",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44000/",
    "code_verifier": ""
  }
}
```

can someone please help me get a xamarin mobile app to work with identity server 3 to call apis?

Comment: any suggestions on why HttpContext.User.Identity is null?  any suggestions on what i can check or go to from here?

Comment: I managed to add claims to my access token by creating a new resource type scope on the identity server.  however HttpContext.User.Identity is still null and IsAuthentication is false even with a valid bearer token.

Comment: I think I need to add bearer authentication to my api app.  Currently it is using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication.  However when being called from a mobile device it uses a bearer token.  I have to somehow get the app to validate the token and set the claimidentity.  I've tried UseOAuthBearerAuthentication but not sure this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your API needs to be registered as a client with your Identity Server as a resource scope.

Then, you need to wire up bearer authentication in your API's middleware by using `UseBearerTokenAuthentication`. This is necessary so that the API can authorize incoming requests that are using the `Authorization` header with the Bearer Schema.

Finally, your mobile app needs to request that scope when issuing an authentication request. However, you also need to make sure your that Mobile app client is registered with that scope in Identity Server